# Google Content Experiments for whole part of the site

Tags: ab-testing, multivariate-testing, google-experiments, content-expiration

I want to run an A/B-test or an experiment for whole part of the site. For example on my /blog/ page, where one variation would have a newsletter form and other variation a free ebook download button.

The problem is that I have to use a full URL path for the experiments, for example /blog/2013/article/1?var=1 and /blog/2013/article/1?var=2 With this method I would need create a new experiment for each blog post. This is impossible.

Any tips on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but the documentation is lacking.

When you choose your variation URLs, you need to use *relative* instead of *http://*. This let's you use query parameters to define the variations, instead of the full URL. In your example, you would define your original page as:

http: //www.example.com/blog/2013/article/1

and your variation URLs would be *?var=1*, *var=2*, etc. using *relative* as the option in the dropdown (instead of *http://* or *https://*).

Here's the not-so-clear documentation on using relative URLs for your variations:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2664470?hl=en&ref_topic=1745208

One important thing to remember is that if you're doing it this way, you need to include the content experiment code on *every* "original" page.

There's also another way to have even more control over serving the variation pages and controlling the experiment using the Content Experiments JavScript API. This is a relatively new feature - you can see the developer documentation about this here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/experiments

Comment: My problem is that I want all pages after http: //www.example.com/blog/.../ to get a var-parameter. It's not specific to http://www.example.com/blog/2013/article/1 or http://www.example.com/blog/2013/article/2 So I want to place the experiment code in the main blog-template and based on the value of the var-parameter the colors of my buttons will change (server side).

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure this is possible. You might look at a more robust yet simple to use tool like Visual Website Optimizer or Optimizely.